# getId() on view obtained from recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY()) is -1

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I've trying to obtain the view.getId(), from the view obtained using  `recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY())`, but it always returns -1

Here's the relevant code:

```
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            View view = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (view !=null) {
                onClick(view);
            }
            return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
        }
```

Here's how I register the gesturelistener:

`gestureDetector =  new GestureDetectorCompat(getActivity(), new RecyclerViewGestureListener());`

I try to obtain the view's id in `onClick(View view)`

Comment: what is the relation between ***view.getId()*** and ***recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY())***  ????

Comment: It seems that you registered for events on a parent of your recycler view when you should register on the recycler view itself to get correct motion event coordinate mapping.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ `recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY())` returns the view?

Comment: @Mariusz I'm in a fragment. How do I register it for a fragment? I'm currently using `getActivity()` as the context.

Comment: @syfy before I answer your question, can you show how you register your gesture detector for touch events? You can edit the post if it would be hard here

Comment: @Mariusz, yeah, sure. Done.

Comment: @syfy and where do you call gestureDetector.onTouchEvent? It should be called in your recycler view's touch listener.

Comment: I never call on touch event. I've created a inner class in my fragment that extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener, where `onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e)` is called on touch events.

Comment: @Mariusz, any idea how I can go about this?

Comment: @syfy 1) register touch event listener in recycler view 2) in onTouchEvent of this new listener call fragment.onTouchEvent 3) now you should get motion events with coords that correctly correspond to the recycler view

Comment: I don't have a class where I extend RecyclerView

Comment: @syfy you don't have to extend recycler view. Just use something like this: recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.onTouchListener() {public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) { detector.onTouchEvent(e); return false; }}

Answer (score 0):

here are some guesses at solutions for the question...I hope I've got it right. please tell me how i do.

**if you are trying to get the `id` of the `View` at the event's position as it is defined in the xml layout**, its very possible that the view with the id that you actually want is the parent of the returned view, so the following code might be what you want:

```
private void onClick(View view) {

    // get a reference to the nearest ancestor View
    // that has an id.
    try {
        while (view.getId() == View.NO_ID) {
            view = (View) view.getParent();
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        return;    // no ancestors with an ID found
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        return;    // cannot cast parent to View
    }

    // got the ID of a view
    view.getId();
}
```

**if you are trying to get the `id` of the `ViewHolder` of the `View` at the event's position**, [`findContainingViewHolder()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#findContainingViewHolder(android.view.View)) might be useful. the following code might help...if it still returns -1, make sure that [`getItemId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getItemId()) in the custom implementation of [`ViewHolder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html) is overridden:

```
@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
    View view = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (view !=null) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = recyclerView.findContainingViewHolder(view);
        if (viewHolder != null) {
            onClick(viewHolder);
        }
    }
    return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
}

private void onClick(RecyclerView.ViewHolder view) {

    // got the ID of the ViewHolder
    view.getItemId();
}
```